# @Embeddable composite primary key with complex fields

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one, composite-primary-key

I have these two tables:

[image]

And I'm trying to map them with JPA/Hibernate like this:
ENTITY:

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "global_task_dependency")
public class GlobalTaskDependency implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1901782042815898352L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private GlobalTaskDependencyPK id;
}
```

PK:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class GlobalTaskDependencyPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2939678921007532701L;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "global_task_id")
    private Task globalTask;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Task parentTask;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_task_id")
    private Task childTask;
}
```

EXCEPTION:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1499)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1422)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
... 97 more
```

Everytime I got NullPointerExeption when trying to run application.
When I replace `Task` fiels with it's real ID which is `Long`, it works fine, but I lose `@ManyToOne` relations.

Any advice how to map correctly?

UPD:
TASK ENTITY:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = TASK_TABLE)
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Task implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8412873233077674082L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;

        @Version
        private int version = 1;

        @Column(name = "taskstatus_id")
        private TaskStatus taskStatus;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "tasktype_id")
        private TaskType taskType;

        @Column(name = "creation_date")
        private Date creationDate;
}
```

Comment: post your Task entity

Comment: @WilderValera added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the relationship (`ManyToOne`) in **`GlobalTaskDependenc.java`** class it self and define the Embeddable `PrimaryKey` class with only foreign key field type.

```
@Table(name = "global_task_dependency")
public class GlobalTaskDependency implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1901782042815898352L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private GlobalTaskDependencyPK id;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "global_task_id")
    private Task globalTask;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Task parentTask;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Task childTask;

}
```

And

```
@Embeddable
public class GlobalTaskDependencyPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2939678921007532701L;


    @Column(name = "global_task_id")
    private Long globalTask;

    @Column(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Long parentTask;

    @Column(name = "parent_task_id")
    private Long childTask;
}
```

Comment: What kind of constructor should I use with GlobalTaskDependency? all args or id only or tasks only?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Although in not recommend using constructor  based composition but if you still want to you can define a constructor  which accept `Task` object. Lets say `GlobalTaskDependency (Task globalTask, Task parentTask, Task childTask)`.